# Random Mouse Lag Triggered by Video/Animation

Tags: windows, video, display, mouse

I'm facing an intermittent issue that seems to occur during video or animation playback in browsers. Since I rarely use any software other than web browsers, I can't confirm if the problem extends beyond them. The issue causes mouse lag, which persists despite troubleshooting with various mice, including both Bluetooth and USB-connected types, to rule out the mouse or its drivers as the source of the problem.

Intermittently, the screen briefly goes black during video or animation playback, accompanied by a subtle shift in color temperature upon returning. At the same time, mouse movement becomes noticeably laggy, making the cursor slow and less responsive. Stopping the video doesn't resolve the issue nor does closing that tab. Both restarting the browser and using the Shift+Ctrl+Win+B shortcut to reset the display drivers can alleviate the mouse lag, but unfortunately, the issue tends to reappear.

Hardware Acceleration: Contrary to expectations, disabling hardware acceleration in browsers did not resolve the issue. The issue manifests in all browsers I tried, including Firefox, Chrome, and Edge, showing that it's not isolated to a specific one.

Driver Updates: My graphics drivers are fully updated, yet the problem remains unresolved.
Graphics Card Swap: Switching from an RTX 3050 to an RTX 4060 did not eliminate the issue.

IGPU Disabling: Attempting to turn off the integrated GPU yielded no improvement.

System Configuration: Dell 8960 i9-14900 CPU, 64 GB RAM, currently running on an RTX 4060 graphics card (initially experienced with an RTX 3050, but the issue persisted post-upgrade), all under Windows 11 Pro version 23H2 (build 22631.3296).

The issue does not manifest consistently with every video or animation, making it difficult to predict or diagnose.

Given the random nature of this problem and the range of attempted solutions, I'm at a loss and would greatly appreciate any guidance, shared experiences, or potential fixes. Is this indicative of a hardware conflict, a software glitch, or perhaps something else entirely?

I used LatencyMon to identify what might be causing the mouse lag and screen issues. It showed potential problems during the episodes, but understanding these results to find a solution is challenging. A screenshot from LatencyMon is attached for reference

[image: LatencyMon while mouse was lagging]

edit: here is hwinfo log https://webeddie.ch/hwilog/rn/hwlog.php?fil=log_qoiwgbze_5799117302.csv

update:
After reinstalling Windows and before adding any other software besides Chrome, the problem persisted. However, when I installed Ubuntu and used it briefly (around a couple of hours), the issue did not occur, although I didn't test it extensively to be certain.

Update: The issue often arises after the computer has been idle for several hours. For instance, if I return after a break, start a YouTube video, switch to full-screen mode, there could be a brief half-second blink, then the mouse becomes laggy. However, if I close and reopen the browser to watch the same video in full-screen, the problem doesn't reoccur immediately. It will play the video fine without any issue

FurMark: https://www.gpumagick.com/scores/show.php?id=50689

update: I've just found out that disabling the RTX 4060 in Windows Device Manager and relying solely on the integrated GPU eliminates the issue. This indicates a GPU-related problem that manifests only after the computer has been idle for a while. Despite replacing the GPU and conducting successful FurMark tests, I still face a blank screen and mouse lag upon returning to my computer. Could the power supply be the culprit, and if so, why does FurMark run without any issues?

Update: My previous update was incorrect. After I disabled the RTX 4060 GPU in the Device Manager, everything was working fine with no lags. However, later when I restarted the computer, not only did the mouse lag return, but it also persisted continuously and wouldn't go away. I then physically removed the GPU from the system, but the mouse lag issue remained, even when I booted into Ubuntu. Eventually, I the GPU (as its far worse and continuous lag without the GPU)

Comment: Could the CPU or something else be overheating? Might be worth seeing what is going on with https://www.hwinfo.com/ during an episode as it can show pretty much every temperature sensor, voltage and speed in your system.

Comment: The monitor going black and coming back with a colour shift is odd though and suggests a monitor disconnect/reconnect. I've seen an old DVI monitor behave oddly on a 3070 with Netflix, which is probably some way the Netflix  website implements DRM causing the graphics card to cycle the connection. How are your screens connected? Maybe a power supply or display issue or even overly long or badly fitting cable or something in your monitor is causing the connection to become erratic and making the graphics card act oddly and make the system behave badly as a result.

Comment: Do you have a different monitor and cable you can try to just rule that out?

Comment: I have a different monitor and cable, but I doubt that is the issue since this monitor and cable worked fine with my previous computer. I'll still try swapping them later to verify though. I plan to run Ubuntu from a USB for few hours to see if the issue persists, which could help rule out hardware problems. Additionally, closing the browser causes the screen to blink (similar to a display reset), eliminating the mouse lag and reverting the (very slight) color temperature, suggesting it's not the monitor. It happens so randomly like once in an hour or more.

Comment: Here is log from  hwinfo https://webeddie.ch/hwilog/rn/hwlog.php?fil=log_qoiwgbze_5799117302.csv

Comment: Is there any chance of a screenshot of the Sensors window when it happens? That log seems clean and looks like you CPU temps are okay, but it leaves out a lot of wider system details that could point at specific issues. Memory doesn't look to be an issue, and there's a moment when your GPU fan starts up, but no load information for the GPU. It only shows one fan, on the GPU which seems odd, unless this is a laptop of some kind.

Comment: Do you have an adblocker installed? Most sites loads *hundreds* of scripts. Any and all of them can cause what you describe.

Comment: I had strange lags and even blackscreen & restart when my GPU was underload. Changing the GPU didn't help. Turned out that the PCIE power cable from the PSU to the GPU was melt.

Comment: Guanyuming, I ran Furmark for a while and encountered no issues. It definitely seems to occur when the computer has been idle for a few hours. When I return and start watching a video in a browser (on any site), that's when the problem arises. https://www.gpumagick.com/scores/show.php?id=50689

Comment: I've just found out that disabling the RTX 4060 in Windows Device Manager and relying solely on the integrated GPU eliminates the issue. This indicates a GPU-related problem that manifests only after the computer has been idle for a while. Despite replacing the GPU and conducting successful FurMark tests, I still face a blank screen and mouse lag upon returning to my computer. Could the power supply be the culprit, and if so, why does FurMark run without any issues?